# Maintaining backwards compatibility while using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack Compose has a min API of 21, but what's the proper way to maintain backwards compatibility back to API 16 or below?

Can we do this with simple build version checks? Something like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       
        // API 16 and below
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
             val someTV = findViewById(R.id.someTV)
        } 
        // API 21 and above
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
             setContent{
                 someComposeUI()
             }
        }
}
```

Comment: That probably technically works (though your app will have no UI for Android 4.4 with that particular `if`/`else if` construction). However, maintaining two separate UI implementations seems like a lot of work. API Level 16 is 9 years old at this point.

Comment: Really it would be API 20 and below then API 21 and above. I copied the version check from somewhere and didn't think too much about the numbers.  At a certain point backwards compatibility becomes unfeasible, but something like `productFlavors` seems more logical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building two `productFlavors` might still be the most realistic approach, because such a configuration will give you [source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html), which strictly tell apart what is being compiled.

```
flavorDimensions "apilevel"
productFlavors {
    legacy {
        dimension "apilevel"
        versionNameSuffix "-legacy"
        minSdkVersion 16
        maxSdkVersion 19
    }
    compose {
        dimension "apilevel"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode android.defaultConfig.versionCode + 50000
    }
}
```

This also gives you `legacyImplementation` and `composeImplementation` for the `dependencies`.